# How to segregate an array of object by using map?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have to form an array of object in another array of object based on id. I was able to group the object based the "applicationId" but was not able to group the inside array of attributes and values array. Also the above code gives me duplicate objects. Please help with this I know its a small fix but I spend whole day still no result.[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-rw91pd?file=src/app/app.component.ts). Expected output commented below in stackblitz

```
 data.map((el) => {
      el.attribute.map((elm) => {
        elm.options.map(em => {
          permissions.push({
            applicationId: el.application, attributes: [{ name: elm.name, value: em.value, disabled: true 
          }]
          })
        })
      })
    });
```

Input Object

```
[
    {
        application: "abc", 
        attribute: [
            {
                description: "abc description1"
                name: "audio"
                options:[
                    {name: "Yes", value: "Y"}
                    {name: "No", value: "N"}
                ]
            },
            {
                description: "abc description2"
                name: "video"
                options:[
                    {name: "true", value: "T"}
                    {name: "false", value: "F"}
                ]
            }
            {
                description: "abc description3"
                name: "call"
                options:[
                    {name: "Yes", value: "Y"}
                    {name: "false", value: "F"}
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        application: "def", 
        attribute: [
            {
                description: "def description1"
                name: "audio"
                options:[
                    {name: "Yes", value: "Y"}
                    {name: "No", value: "N"}
                ]
            },
            {
                description: "def description2"
                name: "video"
                options:[
                    {name: "true", value: "T"}
                    {name: "false", value: "F"}
                ]
            }
            {
                description: "def description3"
                name: "call"
                options:[
                    {name: "Yes", value: "Y"}
                    {name: "false", value: "F"}
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Expected Output:

```
permissions:[
    {
    applicationId:abc
    attributes:
        [
            {
            name:audio
            value:["Y","N"]
            disabled: true
            },
            {
            name:video,
            value:["T","F"]
            disabled: true
            },
            {
            name:call,
            value:["Y","F"]
            disabled: true
            }
        ]
    },
    {
    applicationId: def
    attributes:
        [
            {
            name:audio
            value:["Y","N"]
            disabled: true
            },
            {
            name:video,
            value:["T","F"]
            disabled: true
            },
            {
            name:call,
            value:["Y","F"]
            disabled: true
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: I have specified the output, can u see the expected ouput

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do so using few array [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)s.

Try the following

```js
var input = [ { application: "abc", attribute: [ { description: "abc description1", name: "audio", options: [ { name: "Yes", value: "Y" }, { name: "No", value: "N" } ] }, { description: "abc description2", name: "video", options: [ { name: "true", value: "T" }, { name: "false", value: "F" } ] }, { description: "abc description3", name: "call", options: [ { name: "Yes", value: "Y" }, { name: "false", value: "F" } ] } ] }, { application: "def", attribute: [ { description: "def description1", name: "audio", options: [ { name: "Yes", value: "Y" }, { name: "No", value: "N" } ] }, { description: "def description2", name: "video", options: [ { name: "true", value: "T" }, { name: "false", value: "F" } ] }, { description: "def description3", name: "call", options: [ { name: "Yes", value: "Y" }, { name: "false", value: "F" } ] } ] } ];

var output = input.map(item => ({
  applicationId: item.application,
  attributes: item.attribute.map(attr => ({
    name: attr.name,
    value: attr.options.map(option => option.value),
    disabled: true
  }))
}));


console.log(output);
```

I've modified your [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-cyswye?file=src/app/app.component.ts).

---

<sup>Sidenote: Please try to post a valid object in the question. It'll make it much easier and quicker to reproduce the issue. Much of my time was spent not in the solution but in fixing the object.</sup>

Comment: Thankyou very much, Its working perfectly.... I spend half day for this without any result, you saved my day